# Book series about a war between magic users and other people with a sport like football meets death

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember that the protagonist (who may be a king) is rallying his people for a war between the magic users and other people, I think.

At one point he meets some will-o-the-wisps and another time he's following where the attacking army has invaded and come up on a town filled with dead bodies. The army that they are trying to stall/fight has a sport they play, which is like football meets death. The king is captured but the antagonist doesn't realise it's him and he is forced to play the sport. He actually is really good at it and rises in the ranks, becoming champion maybe.

I can't remember much more but I really want to finish the books to see how it ends as I only read half of the series.

Comment: Never mind everyone I finally googled the right key words and found my answer. It was the Sword of Truth series by Terry Goodkind

Comment: Probably common trope, but it sounds a bit like Goodkind's Sword of Truth books.  EDIT: Ah, allright, it is, there ya go.  You can self answer if you like.  If it helps, the sport bit is towards the end of the series... *Chainfire* or *Confessor*, somewhere in there.

Comment: @abrey1985: In which case, you can post that as the answer (and explain why it's the right answer, and you can accept it in about two days. :)

Comment: @Radhil OP never came back, so how 'bout kicking that one out of "unaswered" tab now? :)

Comment: @Jenayah - there ya go.

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214633/story-where-in-the-second-part-the-hero-gets-kidnapped-by-a-paincult

Answer (score 6):

So, this had been self-answered by the user in comments, but to make it clear and kick it out of the unanswered queue...

[The book is **Confessor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confessor_(novel)), the last novel in the *Chainfire* trilogy in the *Sword of Truth* series by Terry Goodkind.

The book starts with Richard Rahl's capture by Imperial Order forces, and unaware of his identity, forced to play in a team gladiator blood sport named Ja'La'Din.  His team inevitably rises to champion status, and challenges even Emperor Jagang's own team, brutally defeating them and humiliating Jagang into declaring the game invalid.